# AngularJS application gathering data from multiple screens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a app that switches between different screens. Each screen collect data from the user by means of user selecting a button and clicking on it or selecting a radio button. There will be at least 5-6 screens. i need ideas on how and where to store the data collected and what's the best way to move between different screens: switch what is displayed inside a div on the page or go to an entirely different page. The data on each screen is coming from the different database tables.

So far I have one screen done - it pulls data from the database(via Web API call) and based on the data pulled, displays a different image in the hyperlink.

What I want to do is capture which hyperlink is clicked by the user and store that value somewhere(a location that will persist until all data is collected and stored in the database) and then move on to the next screen. I am sort of stuck here and need some help and ideas.

here is what i got so far:

UI for screen 1:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Types</title>
<script src="../../Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="TypesCtrl.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <h3>Select a type</h3>
    <br />
    <table>
        <tr>

            <td ng-repeat="Type in Types">

                <a href="#"><img src="Images/type1.png" ng-show="Type.TypeId=='1'" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/type2.png" ng-show="Type.TypeId=='2'" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/type3.png" ng-show="Type.TypeId=='3'" /></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="Images/type4.png" ng-show="Type.TypeId=='4'" /></a>
    </td>


    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my angular controller:

```
(function () {
    angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", TypeCtrlFunction);

    TypeCtrlFunction.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
    function TypeCtrlFunction($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:49358/api/myAPI/GetTypes').
        then(function (result) {
            $scope.DeviceTypes = result.data;
        });
    };
})();
```

I'd appreciate some help to get me moving forward

Comment: First, i think you should use views, a view for each screen, I recommand that you create a service for each screen too, each screen service stores the data needed from that specific screen (on click events), then you create another service that collects the stored data in previous services and send that data to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data between the different states/controllers either by setting up a service or by using rootScope. Typically it is better practice to use a service. Then you can change views using uiRouter. An example for setting up states:

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");

$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
  })
  .state('main.mainstuff', {
    url: '/mainstuff',
    templateUrl: 'mainstuff.html'
  })
  .state('main.secondstuff', {
    url: '/secondstuff',
    templateUrl: 'secondstuff.html'
  });
}]);
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZDHkFz3fQmXniqrYh7Is) is a plunker showing how implement using nested states. This example uses rootScope but you should consider using a service as AndyHasIt mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

You coude use ui-routing for swithing between different views. As for storing data there are two ways i would do it. One is using services to store values or you could also use local storage or cookies in browser for the same

Answer (score 1):

To share data between controllers, use a service:

```
app = angular.module('MyApp', []);
app.service('SharedDataService', function() {
  return {
    someVar: 'hello'
  }
})

app.controller('Controller1', function(SharedDataService, $scope) {
  $scope.value1 = SharedDataService.someVar;
})

app.controller('Controller2', function(SharedDataService, $scope) {
  $scope.value1 = SharedDataService.someVar; //The same value
})
```

To load different pages within the same page I suggest you use [ngRoute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route#example) or [uiRouter](https://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/)